# Can't use `Authorization: Token xxx` header as identification to request data

Tags: javascript, http

When I login the rest_auth API, I get the data:

```
{"key":"727ac2daf3f0ad2fa1cd13e0905e9941d721f49b","user":{"username":"111111@gmail.com","first_name":"","last_name":"","email":"111112@gmail.com","last_login":"2021-05-18T16:35:12.982804+08:00"}}
```

but when I use the `key` as identification to request data, I get 403 forbidden error:

**[General]**

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/CNAME/list/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**[Response Headers]**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 08:35:13 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

**[Request Headers]**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Authorization: Token 727ac2daf3f0ad2fa1cd13e0905e9941d721f49b
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Well, I suppose you are running the API yourself (http://127.0.0.1:8000), so you need to check what format you expect the Authorization header. Usually the format can be Bearer token or simply token, but Token token is quite unusual